# Number of answers indicated by notification is one more than actual

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications

Here's something which I noticed first in SuperUser yesterday but dismissed it, this time I saw this in SO. I logged onto SO today, and there was a notification - "You have 2 new answers and 1 new notification". 
[alt text http://img535.imageshack.us/img535/3633/uploadq.jpg](http://img535.imageshack.us/img535/3633/uploadq.jpg)

---

I clicked on the link, it shows me there is only 1 answer and 1 comment.

[alt text http://img535.imageshack.us/img535/2697/uploadr.jpg](http://img535.imageshack.us/img535/2697/uploadr.jpg)

The same happened yesterday on SuperUser as well

Comment: I see this every time I log into StackOverflow and have new answers. Whenever I have e.g. 3 new answers, it always tells me I have 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed - [see Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44158/you-have-1-new-answer-see-your-responses-link-doesnt-show-any-responses/44167#44167) for details!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely an answer was deleted by its owner before you clicked on the link.  Once you reach 10K pts, you will be able to see deleted answers.

Comment: Hm, hadn't thought of that aspect.

Comment: However, you don't see deleted answers in the notifications.