# "You have x new answers" show +1 answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, notifications

I've observed that whenever I ask a question and there are answers, the number which appears in the message "You have x new answers" is the actual number of answers + 1.

Comment: If you're 10k, check for deleted.

Comment: nope, no deleted. (at least not on my 3 most recent questions)

Comment: possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42891/superuser-answer-notification-bug

Comment: Dupe - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39059/number-of-answers-indicated-by-notification-is-one-more-than-actual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed - [see Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44158/you-have-1-new-answer-see-your-responses-link-doesnt-show-any-responses/44167#44167) for details!